# Paginate sub document MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pagination

I'm trying to make a paginate mechanism for our product documents stored in MongoDB. What makes this tricky, is that each document can have several colors, and I need to paginate by these instead of the document itself. E.g. the example below has two colors, and should then count as 2 in my paginate results.

How would anyone go around doing this the easiest / most affective way?

Thanks in advance!

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId("4fdbaf608b446b0477000142"),
        "created_at": newDate("14-10-2011 12:02:55"),
        "modified_at": newDate("15-6-2012 23:55:43"),
        "sku": "A1051g",
        "name": {
            "en": "Earrings - Celebrity"
        },
        "variants": [
            {
                color: {
                    en: "Blue"
                }
            },
            {
                color: {
                    en: "Yellow"
                }

            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Do you need strict pagination with a static set of links to pages? Or can you get away with a loose “Show more” solution? The latter should be easy to do by iterating over the cursor and keeping track of both the variant count and the cursor position (to which you can then `skip`).

Comment: The ideal situation is using strict pagination - however if its just not possible, we'd have to use some latter.

Comment: I think it should be possible to write a map/reduce query that would return an array of offsets, but off the top of my head I can’t tell exactly how.

Comment: Strange to paginate on product options in such a manner. I would personally unwind the variants and combine them with the doc _id creating a structure such as _id: {id: _id, variant: blue} and fill the rest of the doc with the information. Using this you can dfo pagination. However MR is not the best way and would not be a realtime solution.

Comment: Originally it was developed as Sammaye suggested, however this was'nt ideal for some of the scripts, so I had to merge the variants within a single document. This however just makes it very very hard to paginate in a reasonable matter. So now I'm just stuck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Sammaye's solution but another approach could just be pulling back more results than you need.

So for example, if you need 100 variants per page and each product has at least 1 variant, query with a limit of 100 to try and get 100 products, and therefore, at least 100 variants.

Chances are, you will have more than 100 variants (each product having more than 1) so build a list of products as you iterate over the cursor keeping track of the number variants.

When you have 100 variants, take note of how many products you have in the list, out of the 100 you retrieved, and use that as the skip for your next query.

This will eventually get expensive for large skips as you will have to seek over the number of documents you skip but could be a good solution for now.

Comment: This means that, in order to build a fixed list of page URLs (with skip counts embedded), you’ll have to iterate over the entire collection.

Comment: Well yeah, but just put next and prev if you are using this solution, or "more"

Comment: Your suggestion is a real solution to my problem. However I find it too consuming, and really need the exact page links instead of a "more" function. This is properly what I'll end up with tho!